# Complementary exercises to Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations by Peter Woit

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am going through Peter Woit's excellent book Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations, however there are very little exercises in the book and I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find appropriate exercises to complement this. I'm a mathematics graduate student so something more on the mathy side would be great.